# What is the equivalent of this Dataflow (1.9.x) pipeline code in Apache Beam?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

Currently I have legacy codebase running in production with Dataflow SDK 1.9.x. Since this 15 August, we won't be able to submit the job with old SDK, we have to upgrade it to latest one, using Apache Beam.

I am in the middle of refactoring the codebase, and found out that the effort is not that simple as change the package name. One of such thing is, we have quite complex logic, uses Accumulator, CombineFn, CoCombine, etc.

Here is our code base looks like (and we have a lot more of this code)

```
  PCollection<KV<String, TrackingData>> keyValueTracking = ...
   Combine.KeyedCombineFn<String, TrackingData, UserEventActivityCountSummaryPerParameter, UserEventActivityCountSummaryPerParameter> perProductActivitySummaryCombined = ...;


PCollection<KV<String, CombineFns.CoCombineResult>> combinedResult = keyValueTracking.apply(
        Combine.perKey(
            CombineFns.composeKeyed()
                .with(identityFn, perProductActivitySummaryCombined, perProductSummaryTag)
                .with(identityFn, generalUserSummaryCombined, generalSummarytag)
                .with(identityFn, firstLastEventCombined, firstLastEventTag)
        ).named("coCombinedPerKey_"+keyValueTracking.getName())
```

My point is how to convert that piece of code to Apache beam with little effort. Currently I can't compile my code base due to ongoing refactoring + my IDEA error tooltip doesn't help either (the message is too long, can see in detail).

Is there any example code that equivalently does my code above?

Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way would be to read the [docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/) here and compare the functions that are the same and make your own internal mapping to understand the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can find in the Dataflow Documentation, a [guide for migrating from SDK 1.x](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/migrate-java-1-to-2#pardo_and_dofn).

One of the things I can point out is the use of the `.named()` method, which was removed and now is required to use `PCollection.apply(“name”, PTransform)` instead.

Since you have more code than this, I suggest to check the guide and the [Apache Beam SDK 2.0 docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/) to get the grasp of what changes need to be done and how to do those.